# Contents of php://input

Tags: php, http

This code:

```
file_get_contents('php://input');
```

returns

> ```
> -----------------------------250932862124141
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"; filename="example.docx"
> Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
> ```
>
> (SNIP: LOTS AND LOTS OF BINARY DATA)
>
> ```
> -----------------------------250932862124141--
> ```

1. I thought `php://input` shouldn't work with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?
2. Does this mean that if I `file_put_contents()` the binary data, I can make a copy of the file?

Comment: Question 1: Why shouldn't it work? Question 2: I'm not sure what the question is? It looks like a file has been uploaded so of course you can copy it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php said states that php://input should work with multipart/form-data. Did I find a problem with their documentation?

Comment: Potentially. What version of PHP?

Comment: @JonStirling Regarding question 2: File put contents could work if I'm just uploading a text file, but it doesn't work well if I'm uploading a different file format.

Comment: This is the PHP version. PHP Version => 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17

Comment: Personally I'd try and give it a test and see if you get the same results on PHP5.6+ and if so potentially raise a bug report (or submit a fix for the documentation).

Comment: Okay, I will try that.

Comment: Fixed the formatting to make the question a bit clearer.